# Rails active storage has_many_attachments permit params issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I want to upload multiple images in form by using active storage but it gives an permit params issue `Unpermitted parameter: :avatars`

```
params.require(:poi).permit(:title, :description,avatars: [])
```

In `_form.html.erb`,

```
<%= form.file_field :avatars %>
```

In `poi.rb`,

```
has_many_attached :avatars
```

In controller,

```
@poi = Poi.new(poi_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @poi.save
    format.html { redirect_to @poi, notice: 'Poi was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @poi }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @poi.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Refer [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads). You have `has_many_attached` relation, Your code will work only for `has_one_attached` relation.

For `has_one_attached`,

```
<%= form.file_field :avatars %>
```

For `has_many_attached`,

```
<%= form.file_field :avatars, multiple: true %>
```

For direct upload,

```
<%= form.file_field :attachments, multiple: true, direct_upload: true %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `multiple: true` in your file field. The file_input should look like this:

---

```sh
<%= form.file_field :avatars, multiple: true %>
```